# Implicit casting of Null-Coalescing operator result

Tags: c#, nullable, null-coalescing-operator, implicit-conversion

With the following understanding about null coalescing operator (??) in C#.

```
int? input = -10;
int result = input ?? 10;//Case - I
//is same as:
int result = input == null? input : 10; // Case - II
```

While, by definition and usage, Case I and Case II are same.

It is surprising to see that in Case-I compiler is able to implicitly cast int? to int while in Case-II it shows error: 'Error  1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'int?' to 'int'"

What is it that I am missing about null-coalescing operator?

Thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make the second case work with the ternary operator, you could use the following:

```
int result = input != null ? input.Value : 10;
```

The `Value` property of the `Nullable<T>` type returns the `T` value (in this case, the `int`).

Another option is to use `Nullable<T>.HasValue`:

```
int result = input.HasValue ? input.Value : 10;
```

The `myNullableInt != null` construct is only syntactic sugar for the above `HasValue` call.

Comment: The first test should use `!=` rather than `==`

Comment: @hvd: Absolutely correct, I blame the OP for having a bad example. :-P Edited.

Comment: Actually, I think your answer is slightly off... `a ? b : c`, where `b` is `int?` and `c` is `int`, is perfectly valid. However, the result has type `int?`, so you'd need `(a ? b : c).Value`. Or your suggested correction, which is spot on.

Comment: The conditional operator does not require absolutely identical operands, it merely requires that no more than one be implicitly convertible to the other when the types *are not* identical.. So in `a ? b : c`, b can be convertible to c, or c to b, and the compiler can figure it out. If both or neither are convertible to the other, you have an error. You can, of course, explicitly cast one or both of the operands to make the expression legal. But I note the question seems to not be about the conditional and why it is illegal, but why the null-coalescing *is* legal.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram: Corrected. I'm leaving my answer up for the sake of providing a different perspective, but hopefully the OP will accept your answer instead.

Answer (score 5):

This behavior you have observed for the null-coalescing operator `??` is a documented language feature, see section 7.13 of the C# 4.0 Language Specification for more details.

> The type of the expression a ?? b depends on which implicit
>   conversions are available on the operands. In order of preference, the
>   type of a ?? b is A0, A, or B, where A is the type of a (provided that
>   a has a type), B is the type of b (provided that b has a type), and A0
>   is the underlying type of A if A is a nullable type, or A otherwise.
>   Specifically, a ?? b is processed as follows:
>
> - If A exists and is not a nullable type or a reference type, a compile-time error occurs.
> - If b is a dynamic expression, the result type is dynamic. At run-time, a is first evaluated. If a is not null, a is converted to
>     dynamic, and this becomes the result. Otherwise, b is evaluated, and
>     this becomes the result.
> - Otherwise, if A exists and is a nullable type and an implicit conversion exists from b to A0, the result type is A0. At run-time, a
>     is first evaluated. If a is not null, a is unwrapped to type A0, and
>     this becomes the result. Otherwise, b is evaluated and converted to
>     type A0, and this becomes the result.
> - Otherwise, if A exists and an implicit conversion exists from b to A, the result type is A. At run-time, a is first evaluated. If a is
>     not null, a becomes the result. Otherwise, b is evaluated and
>     converted to type A, and this becomes the result.
> - Otherwise, if b has a type B and an implicit conversion exists from a to B, the result type is B. At run-time, a is first evaluated. If a
>     is not null, a is unwrapped to type A0 (if A exists and is nullable)
>     and converted to type B, and this becomes the result. Otherwise, b is
>     evaluated and becomes the result.
> - Otherwise, a and b are incompatible, and a compile-time error occurs.

See section 7.14 for why the conditional operator `a ? b : c` works differently.

[Download the specification](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=7029) to read both in completeness at your leisure.

Answer (score 0):

```
int result = input == null ? input : 10;
```

You got your condition mixed in the second case - *you probably meant*:

```
int result = input != null ? input : 10;
```

Now this won't compile because both types in use with the ternary operator must be exactly identical (and `int?` is not the same as `int`) - you can use a simple cast as a solution:

```
int result = input != null ? (int)input : 10;
```

Answer (score -1):

A more concise explantion:

```
int? NULL_Int = 1;
int NORM_Int = 2;

NULL_Int = NORM_Int;  // OK

NORM_Int = NULL_Int;  // NO, you can't assign a null to an int
```