# Implicit conversion with null-coalescing operator

Tags: c#, null, implicit-conversion

I discovered a strange behaviour of my program and after futher analysis, I was able to find that there is probably something wrong either in my C# knowledge or somewhere else. I beleive it's my mistake but I cannot find an answer anywhere...

```
public class B
{
    public static implicit operator B(A values) 
    {
        return null; 
    }
}
public class A { }

public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A a = new A();
        B b = a ?? new B();
        //b = null ... is it wrong that I expect b to be B() ?
    }
}
```

The variable "b" in this code is evaluated to null. I don't get why is it null.

I googled and found a response in this question - [Implicit casting of Null-Coalescing operator result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898223/implicit-casting-of-null-coalescing-operator-result) - with the official specification.

But following this specification, I can't find the reason why "b" is null :( Maybe I'm reading it wrong in which case I apologize for spamming.

> If A exists and is not a nullable type or a reference type, a compile-time error occurs.

...that's not the case.

> If b is a dynamic expression, the result type is dynamic. At run-time, a is first evaluated. If a is not null, a is converted to dynamic, and this becomes the result. Otherwise, b is evaluated, and this becomes the result.

...that's also not the case.

> Otherwise, if A exists and is a nullable type and an implicit conversion exists from b to A0, the result type is A0. At run-time, a is first evaluated. If a is not null, a is unwrapped to type A0, and this becomes the result. Otherwise, b is evaluated and converted to type A0, and this becomes the result.

...A exists, implicit conversion from b to A0 does not exist.

> Otherwise, if A exists and an implicit conversion exists from b to A, the result type is A. At run-time, a is first evaluated. If a is not null, a becomes the result. Otherwise, b is evaluated and converted to type A, and this becomes the result.

...A exists, implicit conversion from b to A does not exist.

> Otherwise, if b has a type B and an implicit conversion exists from a to B, the result type is B. At run-time, a is first evaluated. If a is not null, a is unwrapped to type A0 (if A exists and is nullable) and converted to type B, and this becomes the result. Otherwise, b is evaluated and becomes the result.

...b has a type B and implicit conversion exists from a to B. 
a is evaluated into null. Therefore, b should be evaluated and b should be the result.

> Otherwise, a and b are incompatible, and a compile-time error occurs.
>   Does not happen

Am I missing something please?

Comment: Shouldn't the operator be overridden to work?

Comment: Very interesting. Note that if you change the last line to `B b = (B)a ?? new B();`, i.e. you write the implicit cast "explicitly" in the code, that makes a difference.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen You're forcing the conversion to take place before the null check, not after, by doing that.

Comment: @Servy Exactly. I found out and wrote in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the specification says (I change to `x` and `y` for less confusion here):

> • Otherwise, if y has a type Y and an implicit conversion exists from x to Y, the result type is Y. At run-time, x is first evaluated. If x is not null, x is unwrapped to type X0 (if X exists and is nullable) and converted to type Y, and this becomes the result. Otherwise, y is evaluated and becomes the result.

This happens. First, the left-hand side `x`, which is just `a`, is checked for `null`. But it is not `null` in itself. Then the left-hand side **is** to be used. The implicit conversion is then run. Its result of type `B` is ... `null`.

Note that this is different from:

```
    A a = new A();
    B b = (B)a ?? new B();
```

In this case the left operand is an expression (`x`) which is `null` in itself, and the result becomes the right-hand side (`y`).

Maybe implicit conversions between reference types should return `null` (if and) only if the original is `null`, as a good practice?

---

I guess the guys who wrote the spec *could* have done it like this (but did not):

> •    Otherwise, if y has a type Y and an implicit conversion exists from x to Y, the result type is Y. At run-time, x is first evaluated and converted to type Y. If the output of that conversion is not null, that output becomes the result. Otherwise, y is evaluated and becomes the result.

Maybe that would have been more intuitive? It would have forced the runtime to call your implicit conversion no matter if the input to the conversion were `null` or not. That should not be too expensive if typical implementations quickly determined that `null → null`.

Answer (score 9):

Why did you expect the null-coalescing operator to return `new B()`? `a` is not null, so `a ?? new B()` evaluates to `a`.

Now that we know that `a` will be returned, we need to determine the type of the result (`T`) and whether we need to cast `a` to `T`.

> • Otherwise, **if b has a type B and an implicit conversion exists from
>   a to B, the result type is B.** At run-time, a is first evaluated. If a
>   is not null, **a is** unwrapped to type A0 (if A exists and is nullable)
>   and **converted to type B, and this becomes the result**. Otherwise, b is
>   evaluated and becomes the result.

An implicit conversion exists from `A` to `B`, so `B` is the result type of the expression. Which means `a` will be implicitly casted to `B`. And your implicit operator returns `null`.

In fact, if you write `var b = a ?? new B();` (notice the `var`), you'll see that the compiler infers `B` to be the type returned by the expression.

Comment: This doesn't explain why changing the declaration to `object b` still produces null.

Comment: @KendallFrey Close enough to it.  The `??` only works if the first and second operands resolve to the same type (or the nullable and non-nullable versions of a type).  The first operand, `a`, is compared to null, and then *converted to be of type `B`*, at which point the implicit conversion turns it to `null`.  It doesn't need to be assigned to anything at all for this to happen.

Comment: The rules that are quoted in the question itself, for the `??` operator, are more relevant (_and_ more complex) than the rules you quote (through Lipperts blog) for the ternary `?:` operator. For example given the variables `bool b = false;
      short? s = 10;
      int i = 10;` the expression **`s ?? i`** is allowed, whereas **`b ? s : i`** does not compile. This answer was first, but other answers are more precise, in my opinion.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen nice catch! I usually refer to that blog post whenever discussing both the ternary and the null-coalescing operators - I tend to forget that those rules apply to the ternary operator only (even though both sets of rules are *very* similar). I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 4):

> > Otherwise, if b has a type B and an implicit conversion exists from a
> >     to B, the result type is B. At run-time, a is first evaluated. If a is
> >     not null, a is unwrapped to type A0 (if A exists and is nullable) and
> >     converted to type B, and this becomes the result. Otherwise, b is
> >     evaluated and becomes the result.
>
> ...b has a type B and implicit conversion exists from a to B. a is
>   evaluated into null. Therefore, b should be evaluated and b should be
>   the result.

You're interpreting this one wrong. Nothing says that `a` to `B` conversion is done before `null` check is performed. It states that `null` check is done **before** the conversion!

Your case fits to that:

> If **a is not null**, a is unwrapped to type A0 (if A exists and is
>   nullable) and **converted to type B**, and this **becomes the
>   result**.

Answer (score 0):

The part we need to look at is the compile-time type of the null-coalescing expression.

> Otherwise, if b has a type B and an implicit conversion exists from a to B, the result type is B. At run-time, a is first evaluated. If a is not null, a is unwrapped to type A0 (if A exists and is nullable) and converted to type B, and this becomes the result. Otherwise, b is evaluated and becomes the result.

To put this into pseudocode:

```
public Tuple<Type, object> NullCoalesce<TA, TB>(TA a, TB b)
{
    ...
    else if (a is TB) // pseudocode alert, this won't work in actual C#
    {
        Type type = typeof(TB);
        object result;
        if (a != null)
        {
            result = (TB)a; // in your example, this resolves to null
        }
        else
        {
            result = b;
        }
        return new Tuple<Type, object>(type, result);
    }
    ...
}
```