# Null coalescing operator and casting with as

Tags: c#

Why can't I use the null coalescing operator (`??`) with a casting using `as`?
In my understanding, casting with `as` produces `null` if the type is not the one of the instance, so I'd think it would try the right part of the expression.

Here is an example of what I mean:

```
void Main()
{
    a instance = new c();

    var test = (instance as d) ?? (instance as c) ?? (instance as b);
}

public class a {}
public class b : a {}
public class c : a {}
public class d : a {}
```

And the error I get:

```
Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'UserQuery.d' and 'UserQuery.c'
```

I understand the use of var is inappropriate in this case, but even when using `dynamic` or `a` (the base type), I get the same error message. The problem seems related to the `??` operator.

Comment: _"Why can't I use"_ - this implies an error, could you add it to your question to help searchability etc?

Comment: Because `d` cannot be a `c` and `c` cannot be a `b`.

Comment: You don't specify the exact error message here. Looks like it would be related to the fact that for `var test = ...` the compiler *must* be able to determine the exact type, but you are trying to make it one of three different types.

Comment: `var` has to be determined at compile time, it can't be all 3 types at once.

Comment: In other words, this is about using `var` and not about using `as` with `??`.

Comment: No, it's deeper than just `var`

Comment: `Why can't I use the null coalescing operator (??) with a casting using as ?` **you can**.  The problem you are seeing is completely unrelated to that question.

Comment: `var test = (a)(instance as d) ?? (a)(instance as c) ?? (a)(instance as b);` will compile, but I'm not sure it's a terribly useful thing to do.

Comment: Why the downvotes ?  It seems to be a legit question for me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to be able to define the type of `test` variable at *compile-time*.  Your 3 expressions you are trying to coalesce are all different types (`d`, `c`, `b`).

More specifically, the coalesce operator needs both expressions essentially to be the same type.  Each of your coalesce operations is being performed with different types on each side of the operator.  To read the full details about this requirement, check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8898305/674326

You could cast each expression to `a` and then you'd be able to compile since the type of `test` could be determined to be `a`.  But then that would defeat the purpose of your exercise wouldn't it?

Comment: Indeed that would defeat the purpose.  I updated the question, using `dynamic` should have solved the return type problem, but the error message (I added earlier) shows that the problem is in the `??` operator.

Comment: Ok, didn't get it on first read.  Where did you get this information ?

Comment: You can read more detail about the way this operator works with respect to types in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8898305/674326

Comment: I guess in my case I fall in the last point.  Thanks for your information, I'll mark your answer as accepted !  (maybe you could update your answer to add this information ?)

Answer (score 3):

`var` is a compile-time construct. It does not support dynamic typing.

Therefore, what you're trying to do is absolutely meaningless. The only possible type of `test` would be `a` - you already have that.

What *would* make sense (and is legal) would be something like this:

```
var someValue = (obj as d)?.someProperty ?? (obj as c)?.someOtherProperty;
```

In this case, there's no dynamic typing - we simply have a different way of getting the equivalent value from two different types. However, even that sounds like a bad idea compared to e.g. using proper polymorphism, or at least using `dynamic`.

Comment: @Ksv3n Of course, why would it? `d` is not derived from `c`. The problem is still the same - there's a type mismatch.

Comment: I updated my question.  indeed, `var` was a wrong choice, but even using `dynamic` I have the same behavior.

Comment: @Shimrod Using `dynamic`, there's no point in using the `as` in the first place. What are you actually expecting from your little experiment here?

Comment: I know, it's just to understand why the `??` operator doesn't work here, given that the operands produce `null` when the type is not correct.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with [as operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cscsdfbt.aspx), it's just because the compiler cannot determine the return type of  (d  ?? c). 
You could solve it by casting at least one operand to `a`

```
var test = (instance as d) ?? (a) (instance as c) ?? (instance as b);
```

This is a shorter sample to observe this behavior

```
c instancec = new c();
d instanced = new d();

a foo = instancec ?? instanced; // Compile error even if we declare foo as a
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplifying the code a bit to this:

```
var test = (instance as d) ?? (instance as c);
```

What would you expect the type of `test` to be? Is it `d` or `c`? The type must be determined at compile time only. The compiler won't implicitly cast it to the respective base types for you. So you need to manually do that as @Ksv3n suggested.